# change date format and store in variable using awk

Tags: awk, date

I have date in format YYYY-MM-DD in variable 'a'. I want to convert it in format YYYYMMDD and store in variable 'b'. The variable is in an awk variable.

How can I do the same ?

Comment: Your variable is variable in shell script or in awk?

Comment: it's in awk file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`gsub`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html):

```
a="YYYY-MM-DD"
b=a
gsub("-", "", b)
print(b)
```

will output:

```
YYYYMMDD
```

`gsub` replaces the first argument with the second in the third, in-place, so we copy the value of `a` into `b` first. We replace the `-` characters with nothing.